# Insert string into a filepath string before the file extension C#

Tags: c#

I have a string that defines the path of a file:

```
string duplicateFilePath = D:\User\Documents\processed\duplicate_files\file1.jpg;
```

I am going to move a file to this location but sometimes a file with the identical name exists all ready. In this case I want to differentiate the filename. I have the crc value of each file available so I figured that may be good to use to ensure individual file names. I can create:

```
string duplicateFilePathWithCrc = duplicateFilePath + "(" + crcValue + ")";
```

But this gives:

```
D:\User\Documents\processed\duplicate_files\file1.jpg(crcvalue);
```

and I need:

```
D:\User\Documents\processed\duplicate_files\file1(crcvalue).jpg;
```

How can I put the crcvalue into the string before the file extension, bearing in mind there could be other .'s in the file path and file extensions vary?

Comment: Try using this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the static methods in the [System.IO.Path](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx&ei=2i-oU-GzOOve7Abr7YHQDQ&usg=AFQjCNFkUFAxh9x1u_x4Bj2XU_4hhjYhvw&sig2=MMURT-I8BDVdEbip7u1m1Q&bvm=bv.69411363,d.ZGU) class to split the filename and add a suffix before the extension.

```
string AddSuffix(string filename, string suffix)
{
    string fDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
    string fName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
    string fExt = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    return Path.Combine(fDir, String.Concat(fName, suffix, fExt));
}

string newFilename = AddSuffix(filename, String.Format("({0})", crcValue));
```

Answer (score 7):

```
int value = 42;
var path = @"D:\User\Documents\processed\duplicate_files\file1.jpg";
var fileName = String.Format("{0}({1}){2}", 
         Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path), value, Path.GetExtension(path));
var result = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), fileName);
```

Result:

> D:\User\Documents\processed\duplicate_files\file1(42).jpg

Answer (score 2):

This can also be achieved by using Replace:

```
using System.IO;

string duplicateFilePathWithCrc = duplicateFilePath.Replace(
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(duplicateFilePath),
    Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(duplicateFilePath) + "(" + crcValue + ")");
```

Comment: The closing parenthesis of the second param should be right after `duplicateFilePath`.

Comment: @Tom : Fixed the closing parenthesis. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
string duplicateFilePath = @"D:\User\Documents\processed\duplicate_files\file1.jpg";
string crcValue = "ABCDEF";
string folder = Path.GetDirectoryName(duplicateFilePath);
string filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(duplicateFilePath);
string extension = Path.GetExtension(duplicateFilePath);

string newFilename = String.Format("{0}({1}){2}", filename, crcValue, extension);
string path_with_crc = Path.Combine(folder,newFilename );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Path` class (it's in the `System.IO` namespace):

```
string duplicateFilePathWithCrc = Path.Combine(
        Path.GetDirectoryName(duplicateFilePath),
        string.Format(
            "{0}({1}){2}",
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(duplicateFilePath),
            crcValue,
            Path.GetExtension(duplicateFilePath)
        )
    );
```

Comment: this will only show new filename with CRC value! not the complete path!

Comment: @AppDeveloper: My initial answer's intention was simply looking to show how to add the CRC in the middle of the filename. I have now enhanced the answer to include the file's full path.